# SAS Access Database Export : Connection failed

Tags: ms-access, sas, export

I am trying to export SAS Dataset to my local in ".mdb" format (Access Database). I am using Proc Export statement but it gives the error "Connection Failed"

Also, When I tried to achieve this using EG "Export" feature (on top of the editor window), I used "Export xyz as a step in Project" , I could not find access format there though excel, txt etc options were available.

I did Proc Setinit and found that SAS/Access interfact to PC Files is installed.

I am using SAS 9.4, SAS EG 7.12 and Access 2013. The code I used is as below -

```
     proc export data=test 
    dbms= ACCESS
     outfile="M:\SASAnalytics\Test\test1.mdb" 
    replace;
    run;
```

And When I tried assigning the libname using

```
    libname mdb "M:\AFolder\BFolder\C.mdb"
```

I got this error - ERROR: Connect: Class not registered.

I guess, there is nothing with the code but the SAS Access Export is not enabled or something. Please suggest what could be the issue and how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your SAS installation is 64-bit and MS Office is 32-bit. If that so, you have to use PC Files as proxy server between SAS and Office. `dbms=ACCESS` is using standard `LIBNAME` as connection. In your case `dbms=ACCESSCS` is needed. Moreover for Access file you must specify file location using `DATABASE=` statment and table name using `OUTTABLE=` option in proc export. Complete code:

```
proc export data=sashelp.class 
   dbms= ACCESSCS
   outtable="Class"
   replace;
   database = "C:\Class.mdb";
run;
```

More Access specific options: [Microsoft Access Database Files](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/67382/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0psac3j16cioen1nq2hkwrnk55y.htm)

Comment: Thank you fl0r3k . But the above code gave me "ERROR: Failed to connect to the Server: ." error. If we want to use the "export" wizard in SAS EG, then also I am not seeing the option for Access export. Can you please suggest waht would be the reason for that ? and how can I enable that ?

Comment: Also, I checked the SAS and Office both are 64-bit.

Comment: And When I tried assigning the libname using libname mdb "M:\AFolder\BFolder\C.mdb". I got this error -  ERROR: Connect: Class not registered